# Vuejs Axios Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, axios

FRONTEND

```
 data() {
    return {
      user_data: [],
      user_id: '',
    };
  },
created() {
    this.getUserData();
    const decode = jwtDecode(localStorage.auth_token);
    this.user_id = decode.user_id;
  },
methods: {
getUserData() {
      axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/${this.user_id}`) // Gets an specif book
        .then((response) => {
          this.user_data = response.data;
        });
    },
}
```

BACKEND SHOW METHOD

```
def show
 user = User.find(params[:id])
   render json: user
 end
```

ROUTE

```
api_v1_user GET    /api/v1/users/:id(.:format)
```

In the code above, I'm getting the user id from my token and fetching his information from the database in my method `getUserData()`. However, when I make the request, instead of bringing the specific user it gives me all the registered users.
P.s: I tried to print the user id inside my `getUserData` method to see if the id is in the variable `user_id` and it is working perfectly but my request cannot get it!!
Can someone help me?

Comment: The issue is in the backend code, you should share the code of the controller

Comment: Can you please show your get request handler ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the code above, I'm getting the user id from my token and fetching his information from the database in my method getUserData()

The order is opposite in the code, it does a request to `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/` with no user id.

Instead, it should be:

```
const decode = jwtDecode(localStorage.auth_token);
this.user_id = decode.user_id;
this.getUserData();
```

In case there's a possibility there is no user id, `getUserData` shouldn't be called.